HTML error in doctype main line in VS-Code
When using the shift+! shortcut in VS Code to generate a basic HTML template (<!DOCTYPE html>), the editor is throwing an "unexpected token" error, specifically pointing at the <!DOCTYPE html> line. This seems to be a basic code snippet, and I'm unsure why it's causing an error. Can anyone help me understand and resolve this issue?
Code Snippet:
HTML
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
 </head>
<body>
<h2>hello world</h2>
</body>
</html>


Try saving the file as a .html file and restart VS Code.

It looks like you added some spaces or something that causes this error please remove all spaces before doctype. And you need to learn some basics about html. Try w3school, It can help you in learning
